# Error when mocking modules with the patch decorator in Django

Tags: python, django, mocking

I'm learning about mocking in Django but can't seem to get my head around patching.

The test_get_name passes but test_patched_get_name fails with `ValueError: Object is of type 'MagicMock', but must be a Django Model, Manager, or QuerySet`

Here are my files:

**utils.py**

```
def get_name(clientid):
    c = get_object_or_404(Client, pk=clientid)
    c_name = c.get_name()
    return c_name
```

**tests.py**

```
class ClientTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.c_instance = mock.Mock(spec=Client, pk=1)
        self.c_instance.name = "Test"

    def test_get_name(self):
        self.assertEqual(Client.get_name(self.c_instance), "Test")

    def test_patched_get_name(self):
        with mock.patch('myapp.utils.Client') as self.c_instance:
            from myapp.utils import get_name
            self.assertEqual(get_name(self.c_instance.pk), "Test")
```

**models.py**

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
```

I assume `get_object_or_404` wants a model rather than a mock object but i'm not sure how to do this.

Full traceback:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_patched_get_name (myapp.tests.ClientTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pathto/myapp/tests.py", line 63, in test_patched_get_name
    self.assertEqual(get_name(self.c_instance.pk)
  File "pathto/myapp/views.py", line 36, in get_name
    cu = get_object_or_404(Client, pk=clientid)
  File "pathto/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py", line 111, in get_object_or_404
    queryset = _get_queryset(klass)
  File "pathto/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py", line 97, in _get_queryset
    "Manager, or QuerySet" % klass__name)
ValueError: Object is of type 'MagicMock', but must be a Django Model, Manager, or QuerySet

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: will you please provide full traceback?

Comment: I have updated with traceback.

Comment: `class Client(models.Model):` this shows, `Client` extend from `models.Model`. Whey its showing `MagicMock`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to test the *get_name* function, I think you should patch Django's *get_object_or_404* instead. What that means is when the test calls *get_name*, instead of calling Django's *get_object_or_404* the code will call a mock object -- the patched function -- that will return some predictable value you stuff into it. Your test then is only meant to verify that *get_name* is working and returning the correct value. It doesn't need to do an actual call to Django's *get_object_or_404* (because that's not what you are testing).

I think your test should look something like this:

```
# make sure you import "patch" from mock
from mock import patch

# Patch the "get_object_or_404" function used inside "get_name"
@patch('myapp.utils.get_object_or_404')
def test_patched_get_name(self, mock_get_object_or_404):

    # The patched function is supplied as a parameter to your test function
    # -- you can give it any name you want (in this case, it's
    # "mock_get_object_or_404").

    from myapp.utils import get_name

    # Set mock function's return value -- the patched function here
    # will return the mock "Client" object.
    mock_get_object_or_404.return_value = self.c_instance

    # Now compare the return value from the "get_name" function to
    # see if it's the same as the dummy client's name.
    returned_value = get_name(self.c_instance.pk)
    expected_value = self.c_instance.name
    self.assertEqual(returned_value, expected_value)
```

Comment: Getting the following error: 'AssertionError: <Mock name="mock.client.get_name()" id="3244477493"> != "Test"'

Comment: I'm not sure how mock creates a class instance based on the model defintion, but I think you have to specify in your mock object the return value for the "get_name" method of the Client class. In your test case setUp, add: self.c_instance.get_name.return_value = self.c_instance.name.